# SQL : FULL OUTER JOIN on null columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I want to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between two tables on several columns, but when both columns are null, they are not considered as equal during the join, so I obtain two different rows. How can I write my join, so null columns are considered as equal ?

I have set up a simplified example :

```
create table t1 (
 id number(10) NOT NULL,
 field1 varchar2(50),
 field2 varchar2(50),
 CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table t2 (
  id number(10) NOT NULL,
  field1 varchar2(50),
  field2 varchar2(50),
  extra_field number(1),
  CONSTRAINT t2_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into t1 values(1, 'test', 'test2');
insert into t2 values(1, 'test', 'test2', null);

insert into t1 values(2, 'test1', 'test1');
insert into t2 values(2, 'test1', 'test1', null);

insert into t1 values(3, 'test0', null);
insert into t2 values(3, 'test0', null, 1);

insert into t2 values(4, 'test4', 'test0', 1);

select *
from t1
full outer join t2 using (id, field1, field2);
```

Result obtained : [image]

Result expected : [image]

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d2e5/1/0)

Comment: Why not just join on the ID columns since they are both primary keys for their respective tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [NVL()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) and a Unique String to substitute NULL:

```
select t1.id,t1.field1,t1.field2,t2.extra_field
from t1
full outer join t2 ON
t1.id=t2.id 
AND NVL(t1.field1,'UID_INSTEAD_OF_NULL')=NVL(t2.field1,'UID_INSTEAD_OF_NULL')
AND NVL(t1.field2,'UID_INSTEAD_OF_NULL')=NVL(t2.field2,'UID_INSTEAD_OF_NULL')
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d2e5/16)</kbd>

Comment: This solution loses any benefit of indexes on field1 and/or field2 unless function based indexes are defined

Answer (score 3):

NVL can be applied on the result so no function is needed in the join condition

```
select
    nvl(t1.id, t2.id) id,
    nvl(t1.field1, t2.field1) field1,
    nvl(t1.field2, t2.field2) field2,
    extra_field
from t1
full outer join t2 on t1.id = t2.id AND t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND (t1.field2 = t2.field2 OR (t1.field2 IS NULL AND t2.field2 IS NULL));
```

Comment: I had to update my query in to places with Husqvik answer (as oposed to the answer VALEX provided). I noticed however Sentinels comment about losing the indexing advantage. I only had 300 rows. But it is good to know. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The results do not make it easy to distinguish a NULL in the data from a NULL that represents a failure to join. When null values are present in data being joined, it is usually preferable to omit them from the results by using a regular join.
See this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190409(v=sql.105).aspx

```
select *
from t1, t2
where t1.id = t2.id and t1.field1 = t2.field1 and t1.field2 = t2.field2;
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `NVL` and convert `NULL` into a scalar value.

```
select *
from t1
full outer join t2 
  ON NVL(t1.id, 0) = NVL(t2.id, 0)
  AND NVL(t1.field1, 0) = NVL(t2.field1, 0)
  AND NVL(t1.field2, 0) = NVL(t2.field2, 0)
;
```

Comment: All indexes are lost unless matching function based indexes are created

Answer (score 0):

Internally Oracle's own code (for refreshing materialised views, for example) makes use of the Sys_Op_Map_NonNull() function for this, which would make your join:

```
select *
from t1
full outer join t2 on (t1.id                         = t2.id and
                       t1.field1                     = t2.field2 and
                       Sys_Op_Map_NonNull(t1.field2) = Sys_Op_Map_NonNull(t2.field2));
```

I'm not sure that its use is officially supported, or if they have started documenting it publically though.

Answer (score 0):

This solution maintains the use of the using clause, but eliminates the one column in the using clause containing nulls (field2). Instead field2 is coalesced in the select list.

```
select id
     , field1
     , coalesce(t1.field2,t2.field2) field2
     , extra_field
from t1
full outer join t2 using (id, field1); --field2 removed from using clause.
```